# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error when submitting html form with file input

Tags: php, html, forms, .htaccess, ini

I am having a problem with uploading an image with a html form. When I submit the form after about 3-5 seconds I get the following error in the browser:

> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

The problem seems to be with images in the 100kb and greater range. Smaller images submit every time, but these larger images submit 1 out of maybe 10 tries. I've set higher values for `post max size`, `upload max file size` etc in the `.htaccess` file but that did not fix the problem.

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form method="post" name="update_form" action="php/editpost" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group"> 
        <label for="img_upload">Select image</label>
        <input type="file" name="img_upload" id="img_upload" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"> 
        <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit" value="Update" name="edit_submit" id="edit_submit">
    </div>

</form>
```

In PHP, I am using 'move_uploaded_file' to move the image to it's destination directory like:

```
if ($_FILES["img_upload"]["name"]) {

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img_upload"]["name"]);
    $imgsrc = $target_file;
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if image file is a actual image and square
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["img_upload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $width = $check[0];
        $height = $check[1];
        if ($width != $height) {
            $error = $error."<br />- The image is not square, please crop it and try again.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        } 
    } else {
        $error = $error."<br />- File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        chmod($target_file,0755); // Change the file permissions
        unlink($target_file); // remove the file
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["img_upload"]["size"] > 1000000) {
        $error = $error."<br />- Your image is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") {
        $error = $error."<br>- Only JPG, JPEG & PNG images are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        $fail .= "There were error(s) while uploading the image:<br />".$error;
    }

    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    else {

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

            $sql = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE `posts` SET `imagesrc`='$imgsrc' WHERE `postid`='$postid' LIMIT 1");

            if ($sql) {
                $success .= '- Image updated successfully.<br />';
            }  else {
                $fail .= "- Failed to update the image.<br />";
            }
        }
    } 
}

header("location:../admincontrol?result_s=".urlencode($success)."&result_f=".urlencode($fail));
exit();
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I included all this code but I think it's probably something that needs to be set in `.htaccess` or `php.ini`?

Comment: Small size images upload successfully?

Comment: Very unlikely that a >100kb less than 1MB would cause any problems. Can't think of any PHP config I've seen that has max post size of a few hundred KB.

Comment: @user3187056 yes very small images upload everytime, above 50kb images upload almost everytime but still fail every now and again. above 100kb seem to only work 1 out of 10 times, give or take.

Comment: @SetSailMedia yes I agree that's what leads me to think it has to be something else I am not seeing.

Comment: @jm1175 this might help you http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

Comment: Just for kicks can you comment out the last two lines (`header() & exit;`), replace with something like `echo( "$success | $fail" );` and see what happens?

Comment: And, what type of environment is this running in? Where is it hosted, or is it running locally?

Comment: @SetSailMedia Still getting the connection reset error when removing the header and replacing it with a echo. The website is running live and is hosted with eco web hosting. thanks

Comment: Do you have another machine to test from? This may stem from your local machine and not your server

Comment: @jm1175 remove some part of your php code and try to figure out which part of code make this problem, at first replace all your php code with an echo 'test'.

Comment: @SetSailMedia Thanks that was it, my macbook is where the problem is coming from, don't know why. Tested it on a another machine running ubuntu and the larger images work every time.

Comment: try to remove enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

removing *enctype="multipart/form-data"* in my form, solved my problem. 
(Thanks to Alex Kapelyukhovskiy)
I had the problem with chrome but not safari.